# Best way to set request parameters to object

Tags: java, performance

I need your recommendations. which way is the best in terms of software engineering (Readability, Usability )

I have object **person**

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }


}
```

I have method **savePerson**.

First way is to set request parameters to variable before initialise object.

```
public void handle(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
    Person person = new Person(name, surname);
    personService.savePerson(person);
}
```

Second way is to set request parameters set them as constructors parameters.

```
public void handle(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Person person = new Person(request.getParameter("name"), request.getParameter("surname"));
    personService.savePerson(person);
}
```

Comment: I prefer the first version for readabity.  Impact on performance between the two: probably none, since the compiler will inline the first version to become the second version.

Comment: The first is definitely more readable

Comment: Another option is to create a constructor that takes the request as an argument

Comment: request as an argument would create a dependency between Person and request class, which is usually not desired, specially if you have multitier design, in which your web stuff is outside the business/dao layer.

Comment: @osdev pls edit your question. Person model you wrote does not match the usage you later explain. You are using Person constructor in both your approaches (which is fine), but the Person model you describe does not include parametrized constructor (and instead it has some setters)

Comment: @albert_nil you caught it :)

Answer (score 2):

The first way is more readable and easy to debug, than the second one. Moreover, if you add other fields in your `Person` object the second way will be totally messy.

In order to simply even more the code you can use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) to avoid writting Getter and Setter for your `Person` class

Comment: you provided broken link

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider that the compiler transforms your operations in a sort of binary version that is a little optimized.
Your second version is less readable but it has only one code line.
The compiler will do it for you, so you can choose your version according to your writing style.
If you have to share your code with other persons, the first method will probably be the best because it is more simple, and in a scenario where the execution efficiency is the same, it can become your discriminant.

Answer (score 1):

First one for sure. It is readable and the instructions are clearly visible. It being basic can be understood by any junior level developer as well so if someone else works on this code, it will be easy for him/her to make the necessary changes.

Always the code that is readable must be used so as to keep the things structured and more manageable.